# Can't start debugging mode in VS Code ReactJS project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I can't start debugging in visual studio code in my ReactJs project and I get this error message.

```
Debugger attached.
(node:19248) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

and when I try to add **"type": "module"**; I get another error which is shown below.

```
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
file:///d:/PATHTOMYCODE/index.js:23
  <Provider store={store}>
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:147:18)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:48:21)
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

*UPDATE*:
It was an issue caused by `.vscode/launch.json` "configurations"

My original file contained:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\index"
    }
  ]
}
```

I changed to :

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

This change got it to work.

Comment: Node does not understand JSX syntax, you either need transpiled code, or you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node , it's the Typescript compiler, but it can also parse JS code.